# Git pagination stopped working

Tags: git, pagination

My Git pagination stopped working. I like to have the default behaviour of Git for pagination, eg. `git diff`, `git log`, etc...

I've tried different things without success:

1. Force to use `less` as pager (with and without options):

   ```
   git config --global core.pager less
   git config --global core.pager 'less -FRXK'
   ```
2. Global setting to use pager, for example I tried with the `diff` command:

   ```
   git config --global pager.diff true
   ```
3. Use some global variables related with pagination:

   ```
   export GIT_PAGER=less
   ```

---

The only thing that seems working is the `--paginate` option, like:

```
git --paginate diff
git --paginate log
```

So, my last attempt was to set an alias for git including `--paginate` for all commands but this is causing another problems, eg. this is not working:

```
git --paginate commit --verbose
```

Any ideas here? How I can force Git to do pagination automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After working in a different repository with the same shell environment (using all Git defaults), I realised that the problem was with this specific repository and not with the Git configuration.

So, I deleted my local repository and cloned again. It worked!

Comment: So basically there was a `.git/config` file in your repository folder with some undesired/undesirable configuration.